# onchange Event doesn't work

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I tied the event onchange to my textbox control:

```
var tbValue = document.getElementById("tbValue");
    tbValue.onchange = function () {
        var tbSelText = document.getElementById("selectText");
        if (tbValue.value == null) {
            tbSelText.value.replace("sada", "");
        }
        else {
            tbSelText.value.replace("sada", "sada" + tbValue.value + "'");
        }
    }
```

When I change tbValue (it's my textbox control with onchange event) tbSelText must change at the same time. But it doesn't.
What I did wrong?

Comment: Let's see the associated HTML.

Comment: Are you expecting the event to fire **when typing**?  If so, it won't... `onchange` will fire on the bluring of the textbox if something has changed.  You probably want `onkeydown`, `onkeypress`, or `onkeyup`

Comment: stick an alert at the very top of your method. If you see the alert, then it is firing and its the code above that's wrong somewhere. If you don't see the alert, then you haven't wired it up properly in your html

Comment: One main thing to check, if this is an asp.net page with a masterpage then your controls may have different ID such as $C_1000_BodyContent_tbValue. Inspect the html in your browser to make sure you are checking the right ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am **guessing** that you're expecting the `onchange` event to fire **while typing**, which is not going to happen.

The `onchange` event only fires when the textbox losses focus (in other words, it blurs) AND if the content has changed.  [See this MSDN for information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ie/ms536912%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)...

> This event is fired when the contents are committed and not while the value is changing. For example, on a text box, this event is not fired while the user is typing, but rather when the user commits the change by leaving the text box that has focus.

If you want an event while typing you should look at one of the `onkeydown`, `onkeypress` or `onkeydown` events.

Answer (score 2):

Verify with below points:

- When the above Js code will get called, the DOM must be ready before
  it, otherwise the tbValue will be null. you can try alerting its value before assigning event.
- The onchange will only fire when you will change something and tab out from text box (i.e.   remove focus).